# How does the Android app get detail routing information?

Tags: java, android, network-programming

There has a Android mobile phone application, it need to interact with the server to exchange message, but sometimes this app can not connect to the server, the server told us that we don't have access to it, so I want to get the detail routing information, such as the app request info， transfor to the router1, router2, router3, finally reached the server, the request info may be interrupted when it arrived at router 2, so that the request info is not delivered to the server, now I want to know how to get the detail route information (app-> router 1-> router 2-> 3...... -> server)

I study the code of Apache/DefaultRequestDirector.java
protected void establishRoute(HttpRoute route, HttpContext context)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2fF1.png)

code comments say
// route: Source -> P1 -> P2 -> Target (3 hops)
// fact:  Source -> P1 -> Target       (2 hops)

I want to know the reason why the request message not sent to the server, because the server said that they are normal, but app did not connect to the server, so I want to know the exact routing information, in order to know where the message is interrupted and the selected route is correct or not(for example: normal: app-> router 1-> router 2-> server, failed: app-> router 1-> router 2->router 3-> router 4 and then interrupted)

Comment: Is this something you expect to control from the device? Monitoring connectivity and handling error responses (and retries) covers the needs of 99.9% of apps developed

Comment: I want to know the reason why the request message not sent to the server, because the server said that they are normal, but app did not connect to the server, so I want to know the exact routing information, in order to know where the message is interrupted and the selected route is correct or not(for example: normal: app-> router 1-> router 2-> server, failed: app-> router 1-> router 2->router 3-> router 4 and then interrupted)

Comment: Presuming you know how IP works, what do you think you can achieve from this? I think it will take a lot of work (with native level code) and not help you with reliability. You're better spending your time implementing automatic retry

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If I don't consider the complexity of implement this function, I want to implement this function what kind of knowledge do I need to learn? Or can you kindly tell me the specific ideas to implement.

Comment: I don't think I can write a solution off the top of my head. I'd guess you'll need some familiarity with linux, C++ for the code and of course good understanding of the IP layers and routing